# Override de tipagem typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Quero adicionar uma propriedade **user** para o request do Express. Para isso criei um arquivo chamado **express.d.ts** com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        user: {
           id: string;
        }
    }
}
```

Ao tentar acessar no meu middleware a propriedade **request.user** criada, tenho o seguinte erro:

```
- error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
```

Código da classe className.ts do middleware:

```
export default function methodName(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void{
    request.user = {
        id: 10,
    }
}
```

Estrutura das pastas:

```
src
     @types
          express.d.ts
     middlewares
          className.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer assim no arquivo de declaração do express que você criou:

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        user?: {
           id: string;
        }
    }
}
```

colocando como opcional

Answer (score -4):

Add essa linha no seu scripts package.json

```
"dev:server": "ts-node-dev --inspect --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules src/server.ts",
```